# Calling a worker service method from API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .net Worker Service that executes a method `ReadCycle()` every minute.
I now have to expand the project so that the method is also callable using an API Endpoint.
For now I got the API endpoint working, but I´m unable to link the `ReadCycle()` with the response in the API Controller.
How would I do that?

Worker where the Method I want to call is:

```
   private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
   private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
   //Stuff

   public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       _logger = logger;
       Configuration = configuration;
   }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ReadCycle();                                
            await Task.Delay(time, stoppingToken);
        }            
    }
    public void ReadCycle()
    {
        //do Stuff
    }
```

API Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Controller:ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post(Model model)
    {            
        //ReadCycle Call here;
        Worker.ReadCycle();  //This is obviously not working
        return CreatedAtAction("POST","Cycle Completed");
    }
}
```

Program

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    //app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access worker like this.

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public ValuesController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void test()
        {
            var worker = serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>()
                                    .OfType<Worker>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
            worker.ReadCycle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: that works, thank you.